# Creating Custom NSString from NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I need a NSString with the format "yyyy-mm-dd - 11:00:00"

Year, month, and date should be from the current date, while hour, minute, and second should be 11,00,00.  I could not figure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `yyyy-MM-dd - HH:mm:ss` (because `mm` is minutes and `MM` is month). But you just need

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd - HH:mm:ss";
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Or if you want it to say `11:00:00`, either pass it that `NSDate`, or you could:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd' - 11:00:00'";
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: It seems he wants time to be 11:00:00

Comment: Yes, But i need the time format to be custom. you code will give me curent date and time. but I need a string like 2013-809-04 - 11:00:00. The time 11.00.00 should always be the same but the date needs to be changed

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - 11:00:00", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
```